# How to solve Iteration Sequence of Matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

[image]

Hi, I need help in solving this question as I don't understand the question very well, and not sure which formula should I use to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: What is $y_n$ here?

Comment: It isn't stated in the question. Hence, I don't know what is Yn....

Comment: @Dutta Should I diagonalise the Matrix A by expressing it in the form of A=PDP-1?

Comment: Yes, Then $A^n = P D^n P^-1$. You may get some limit.

Comment: another other method to solve this?

Comment: I do not know. Hope somebody shall come to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is the power method to obtain an eigenvector $v$ associated to the greatest eigenvalue (in absolute value) $\lambda$ of $A$ ; indeed $[x_n,y_n]^T=A^n[x_0,y_0]^T$, when $n$ is great enough, is s.t. $\dfrac{y_n}{x_n}\approx \dfrac{v_2}{v_1}$.

Here $\lambda=23+3\sqrt{13}$, $v=[9,6+3\sqrt{13}]^T$, and $\dfrac{v_2}{v_1}\approx 1.8685$.

For instance, $\dfrac{y_{12}}{x_{12}}\approx 1.8685$.